# Unable to navigate to another Stack with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to navigate from a screen ('Settings' screen to 'Auth' in the below example) when the user signs out using `navigation.navigate('Auth')` but I get an error: "Do you have a screen named 'Auth'?"

I don't understand what's wrong here. In react-navigation 4 this was possible.

PS: Feel free to ignore the token part.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Login from './src/screens/Login'
import Register from './src/screens/Register'
import Welcome from './src/screens/Welcome'
import Map from './src/screens/Map'
import Shop from './src/screens/Shop'
import OfferConfirmation from './src/screens/OfferConfirmation'
import Settings from './src/screens/Settings'



const AuthStack = createStackNavigator()
const AuthStackScreen = () => (
  <AuthStack.Navigator>
    <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
    <AuthStack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
  </AuthStack.Navigator>
)

const MainStack = createStackNavigator()
const MainStackScreen = () => (
  <MainStack.Navigator>
    <MainStack.Screen
      name="Map" component={Map}
    />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Shop" component={Shop} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="OfferConfirmation" component={OfferConfirmation} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
  </MainStack.Navigator>
)

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default () => {

  const [token, setToken] = useState(null)

  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>

      {token ?
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainStackScreen} />
      :
        <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackScreen} />
      }

    </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PS: Feel free to ignore the token part.

That's the important part. You're defining the `Main` screen when token is present, and `Auth` when token is not present. If token is present, you have a single screen named `Main`, there's no `Auth` screen defined. So you cannot navigate to it. Similarly, when token is not present, there's only `Auth` screen, so you cannot navigate to `Main`.

> when the user signs out using `navigation.navigate('Auth')`

When the user signs out, you should not manually `navigate` to `Auth`. Instead you should just delete the token (`setToken(null)`). Then React Navigation will automatically show the `Auth` screen since you have it defined when token is `null`.

More details in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Comment: Well I am a bit hesitant to do all this work with Context but ok. So you say that normally navigating to "Auth" would work if the token part wasn't there?

Comment: I cannot make context work right. The example on the site is clearly incomplete. I don't know why you keep posting incomplete examples there.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the fact that you, personally, have answered my questions quite a few times. But at the same time I truly believe that you guys are not doing your best in the tutorial in expo and react-navigation.